# Link local postgres database with heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Is it possible to create a link between a running Heroku PostgreSQL instance and one running locally?

So far the only documentation I've found is [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/heroku/3.42.45/Heroku%2FCommand%2FPg%3Alinks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but when I need to run some queries on my Heroku Database I simply connect to it using PgAdmin, so I can run local queries and see my data without having to use the console or writing code.

Hope that helps!

http://agileforce.co.uk/heroku-workshop/heroku-postgres/pgadmin.html